# The most efficient way to set cookies using the cookies.set() API?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, setcookie

I am developing an add-on, and want to set cookies manually. In particular, I will find the "set-cookie" header and extract its value like `fr=14myabcdeWHEoomo..BfTm-f.Yl.AAA.0.0.BfTnHV.AWVO5tm-; expires=Mon, 30-Nov-2020 16:07:48 GMT; Max-Age=7775999; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; secure; httponly; SameSite=None`.

While I can use a loop to split the string, find each name-value pair and call `cookies.set()` multiple times to set all cookies, I wonder if there any standard API that can recognize the format of such string, and set all the cookies all at once, so I don't need to manually loop through the string and manually set properties such as `httponly`.

Comment: There's no such API for extensions. You can find a js library to parse such cookie strings.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!